# What's causing [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'd:q'?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've two entries in my MariaDB 10.5 error log file last night:

```
[ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'd:q'
```

I've looked at my nginx access log around that time and can't see any unusual entries.  I've searched for that error with the d:q bit and got no hits.  Anyone know what this could be?  Does it suggest my server has been exploited in some way...?

Thanks

Comment: Possible similar Q&A [ERROR Invalid (old?) table or database name](https://serverfault.com/q/654406/145804) (Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following day I got the same errors at exactly the same time (2am and 2:05am), so looked into it more.

The `:q` felt like a bit of a clue to me.  I couldn't really understand how I could have accidentally affected MariaDB when (failing) to quit vim... but I went looking in my `/var/lib/mysql` directory, and sure enough there was an empty directory `d:q`.  Deleted it and I'm assuming the problem will go away.